# Finding a polynomial $g(x)$ such that $ g(x)g(x-1)=g(x^2)$

Tags: polynomials

Find all polynomials $g(x)$ with real coefficients with the property $$g(x)g(x-1)=g(x^2).$$

My try: I found $$g(x)=(x^2+x+1)^n$$
satisfies the condition; maybe there are other solution? If so, how to prove it (and/or find them)?

Thank you.

Comment: __Hint:__ What can you say about the roots of the polynomial?

Comment: $g=0$ and $g=1$ are solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** What can you say about the roots of the polynomial?

(The following are steps. Fill in the rest of the details yourself. It should be clear why this works. I removed as much text as possible due to OP's request in comments.)

If $g(x) = g$ is constant, then $g^2 = g$.

Otherwise, $\deg g \geq 1$. Let $g(\alpha) = 0 $.

Step 1: $g( \alpha) = 0 \Rightarrow | \alpha | = 0 $ or 1.

Step 2: If $\alpha = 0 \Rightarrow g(n^2 ) = 0\, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. $\Rightarrow \Leftarrow$

Step 3: If $|\alpha |= 1 \Rightarrow \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, \alpha^n = 1$.

Step 4: If $\alpha^n = 1$, then for $\beta = (\alpha + 1)^2$, we have $g(\beta) = 0 $.

Step 5: $\alpha = ??$

Step 6: If $(x-\alpha)^m \mid g(x) \Rightarrow (x-\beta)^m \mid g(x).$

Step 7: Hence $g(x) = (x^2 + x+1)^n$.

Comment: Nice guide for the solution!

Comment: Hello,My English is not good,plese don't say more  text ,can you take more mathematical,That I can understand

Comment: @chinamath Sure, they are all in math statements now. Fill in the details yourself.

Comment: HaHa,Thank you,I like math statements,Thank you

Comment: Thank you,can you help me see this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530887/how-find-this-maxium-s-delta-abc?rq=1